# Instruct MSBuild to only build integration tests but not run them

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, roslyn

I'm trying to use MSBuild (.props/.targets) to achieve a smooth experience when running tests and NOT run integration tests. I've trying different ways

- Remove `**\*.IntegrationTests.dll` after build (doesn't work)
- Exclude `**\*.IntegrationTests.csproj` before build (doesn't work)
- Set `CopyToOutputDirectory=Never` if `IsIntegrationTestProject=true` (doesn't work)

My goal is to achieve

1. Running tests in VS or from CLI doesn't run integration tests. This must be explicit
2. Skip running integration tests on CI-builds and only run them when explicitly called for, example setting environment variable, AzDo variable, MSBuild property.

Things I've tried

```xml
// Directory.Build.props
<ItemGroup>
  <IntegrationTests Include="**/*.IntegrationTests.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

// Directory.Build.targets
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(RunIntegrationTests)' == 'false'">
  <Delete Files="@(IntegrationsTests->Replace(".csproj", ".dll")) />
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
  <MyProjectReferences Remove="@(IntegrationTests)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If anyone can shed some light over this I will be very gratefully.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you reun the test? with vs test task in azure pipelines?

Comment: The test are currently run by SonarQube. But I'm aiming at make this work for 1. From VS/ReSharper 2. `dotnet test`

Comment: In the `dotnet test` you have the `--filter` flag, you can exclude there the integration tests dlls.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that by I'm trying to achieve this using MSBuild so that the experience of "Right click Solution > Run tests" could be left intact from what people are used of, and that is that integration tests are not run. Having the test-filter and category left as last resort. Can --filter be used exclude tests that av "IntegrationTest" in their namespace? Thank you

Comment: It supports Name, FullyQualifiedName, ClassName, Priority, TestCategory.

Comment: So the `--filter "FullyQualifiedName!~IntegrationTests` doesn't work in Git Bash but works in Command Prompt.. Annyoing...

Comment: MSbuild is used to manage build instead of managing whether to run tests. Since you're not trying to run the IntegrationTests, maybe we can exclude it from build process?

Comment: I would still like them to be built to catch build errors early. What I envisioned was a way to achieve the `dotnet test --filter <filterExpression>`  experience from within VS using MSBuild. Perhaps declare a test project with `IsIntegrationTest`, in .props inside test-folder add `<VsTestFilterExpressions>FullyQualifiedName!~IntegrationTests</..>` or use the `IsIntegrationTest`-property. Run Tests from within VS will honor the settings and simply skip either filter expressions or other setting.

Comment: Hi, where do you place the `Directory.Build.xxx`, in solution directory or project directory? And could you share the details about your test task so that we can further research it :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I created a repository https://github.com/joacar/MSBuildLab, hope this make it clear what I'm trying to achieve :) Thanks for taking time